# help! sound devices mixpre + Fostex fr2le correct setup

Tags: fostex

hope somebody can clarify this doubt once and for all!

So, I have a fostex fr2-le and recently bought a sound devices mixpre. Not mix-pre D, but the first version. In order to take advantage from the superb preamps, I suppose I need to convert line to mic level, from mixpre +4dbv to fostex -10dbu; meaning I need a 50db atenuator such as Shure a15la, but I also need to go from XLR to 1/4 TRS to bypass fostex preamps.
Is this correct? Is it the best/only setup possible?
I'm not sure if the atenuator is needed, because fostex input is one of those simultaneous XLR/phone input, which means mic/line, so can I assume it can receive either +4dbv in TRS or -10dbu in XLR? In that case I should only need xlr-Trs cable?
I've been reading several threads, but cant find the proper answer.
Thank you!
Pedro